# Rails - customizing the flash message for specific use case

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm completely new to ruby on rails. Please help me out with the below use case.

By default flash messages are configured to timeout and fade in few seconds in application.html.erb

```
<div id="message" class="modal alert alert-error fade clear" data-alert="alert">
    <%= flash[:notice] %>  
</div>
```

Javascript code to set the timeout for the flash:

```
 var showFlashMsg = function(){
<%if flash[:notice].nil?%>
    return false;
<%else%>
    return true;    
<%end%>}



if(showFlashMsg()){
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        showMsg();
    }, 100);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        closeMsg();
    }, 500);
  }
```

showMsg() and closeMsg() holds #message.show() and #message.hide() functions.

But i'm trying to override that above mentioned behavior by making specific flash alert messages user dismissable (ie., adding the close button to the flash alert.) - in case the flash message is triggered when i submit the particular form.

So in this case, i need to override the default behavior set for the flash by adding the close button and removing the closeMsg() timeout for those flash. Except the flash messages which are displaying the form submission response, all the other flash messages triggered by **same controller and the same action** should follow above mentioned behavior of fading out within few seconds.

Please give me some suggestions on how to customize the flash messages only for the particular form submission response using javascript and rails?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I have used the toastr library with good success https://medium.com/@shilpikayal/toastr-js-with-rails-5-b7677bd56b52

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite the first bit of code as:

```
 var showFlashMsg = <%= !flash[:notice].nil? %>
```

Then assuming you know what string you're looking out for in your notice:

```
<% special_string = "This is the special flash notice" %>
var showFlashMsg = <%= !flash[:notice].nil? %>
var setTimeout = <%= flash[:notice] && flash[:notice] != special_string %>

if(showFlashMsg){
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    showMsg();
  }, 100)
}
if (setTimeout){
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    closeMsg();
  }, 500);
}
```

This will set `showFlashMsg` to true if `flash[:notice]` is not nil, and  `setTimeout` to true if it's not nil, and also doesn't equal the special string.

Comment: Thanks for the response !!. But I have a list of 7 alert messages. So based on the form submission status, the alert message will vary. Also, all these 7 alert messages are **localized in different languages**.  I will be getting the localized flash message from the controller. so in that case, i can't predetermine the string.